# How to add two arguments using Typescript Generics in Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For example I have this code in `.tsx file` extension

```
const Add = <T,>(arg0: T, arg1: T): T => arg0 + arg1;
const A = Add(1, 2);
const B = Add('1', '2')
```

My problem is that there's an error saying:

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'.ts(2365)
```

Is there a workaround on how to use it in **Arrow function** with **Generics**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you want to [constrain](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) your generics to things you actually intend to use with the `+` operator; presumably `string` or `number`.  Then, this will still fail, because the compiler will balk at adding `string | number`.  Worse, constraining a generic parameter to extend `string | number` will cause the compiler to interpret the input as a either a [string literal](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) or a [numeric literal](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) type, and you do not want the return type of `Add(1, 2)` to be `1 | 2`.

The easiest workaround is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and a [conditional type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) for the return, which widens the result to either `string`, `number`, or `string | number`:

```
const Add = <T extends string | number>(
    arg0: T, arg1: T
): T extends string ? string : number => arg0 as any + arg1;

const A = Add(1, 2); // number
const B = Add('1', '2') // string
Add(1, "2"); // compile error
Add("1", 2); // compile error
const C = Add(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : "1", Math.random() < 0.5 ? 2 : "2"); // string | number
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggEwTAvDAPAFRgUwB5Q5gIQzQBOAlmAOYwA+MYArgLYBGO5AfABQCwAKBgiYAQ3I0ADAC4YmADTjJARjmYhASnW4CREmShVaMAPyHjdOSw5dU3ZdPGkxYAJ4wA1I5UBuIaCQsHCo8Ei8KkoATJr+goHQMABCoYgIvADkKhlKGVEZmkJpEUoARFGlsTAA9NUwoKwADpQANji45OQg5EXhpSql0VW19SBNre1cXT3x4IkAwqnhALJiUAAWAHTkrghjvJoYMFKbAKxmMCowcv2DMKsb27v7h+jHZxdR1zDllb41dQo1DojBsnHIMCAA)

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IAdd {
  (a: number, b: number): number
  (a: string, b: string): string
}
const Add: IAdd = (a: any, b: any) => a + b;
Add(1, 1);
Add("1", "2");
```

Comment: But not in arrow function

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers